# How to append or remove an element from an existing array in kuzzle

Tags: kuzzle

Let's imagine this situation
Alice and Bob are connected to the same kuzzle server.
There is a document structured like this:

```
{
  "nom": "Festival de l'automne",
  "participants": [id1, id2, ...]
}
```

Alice and bob want to update the document nearly at the same time.
If using `kuzzle.document.update()` i have to use a previously stored value on Alice's or Bob's client to update the participants array. That can lead to conflict or data loss.

My question is is there a way to update the "participants" array using the previous values server side ? or is there a way to directly use an elasticsearch query in order to user scripts like

```
{
  "script" : "ctx._source.participants += participants",
  "params" : {
    "participants" : "idx"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kuzzle does not expose Elasticsearch scripting features for security reasons (privilege escalation and heavy scripts that could DOS the server).

You should expose a specific API action to atomically appends new values to an array. This API action should use the [Integrated Elasticsearch Client](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/main-concepts/data-storage/#integrated-elasticsearch-client) to use a painless script.

You can find more information about how to deal with array in the [documentation](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/main-concepts/data-storage/#arrays)